# Is there any java class can round any type of number to some specified precesion?

Tags: java

I want to round a long range values based on its type (BigDecimal, Long, Double, ...) to some specified precision which can be different depending on the type. some thing like this:

public [type] roundValue ([type] value, int percesion){//...}

is there any util class for this process?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. In that signature, the precision doesn't depend on the type, it's an explicitly provided parameter.

Comment: Guess via method overloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with BigDecimal actually, and you can create your own utility class that uses method overloading.

```
public class Rounding {

    public static BigDecimal round(BigDecimal value, int prec) {
        return value.round(new MathContext(prec));
    }

    public static long round(long value, int prec) {
        return new BigDecimal(value).round(new MathContext(prec)).longValue();
    }

    public static double round(double value, int prec) {
        return new BigDecimal(value).round(new MathContext(prec)).doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method overloading can help. Thanks.

Comment: The `double` version of this doesn't really work.  Doubles can't store numbers with a specified decimal precision in the first place.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're right in that the precision won't be stored, but it's still going to round the floating-point value to the specified precision.  For example, `Rounding.round(555.555d, 4)` will return `555.6`.

Comment: @BenM.: Counterexample: `double d = 0.003830310554564176`.  `d` has 18 decimal places, but if you try rounding it to 17 decimal places using your `round(double, int)` method, you will get back the same number, still with 18 decimal places.  (I just randomly generated that.)  `double` can't _represent_ the 17-decimal-place rounded version in the first place.

Comment: What is going to be the solution?

Comment: @Nisman: The solution is to never, ever use `double` when you need a specific number of decimal digits.  Always use `BigInteger`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The word "precision" is adding some confusion to this I think.  A better term would be "significant digits."  It's not trying to round 17 decimal places, it's trying to round 17 significant digits.  To use a modified version of your example, calling `Rounding.round(0.003830310554564176d, 4)` would give you `0.00383`.

Comment: my value types are already defined and I have to round them anyway and double is in them.

Comment: @BenM, my bad; here's a better example: `0.18967170727446725`, with 17 digits.  When I pass that to your methods asking for 16 significant digits `BigDecimal` returns `0.1896717072744673`; `double` returns `0.1896717072744672`.

Comment: @Nisman: the correct answer is that there is no way to do that for `double`, and you shouldn't try.

Comment: The short explanation is that there are some valid decimal numbers `double` simply can't represent.  When you store `0.1` as a `double` it isn't actually `0.1`; it's actually `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.  That inaccuracy can lead to rounding errors that make little sense.  Or, for sufficiently large integers `n`, it can store `n.5` but not `n.6`; it goes straight to `n.75`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're making some good points about how a floating-point value will never exactly equal a decimal value, but I don't think you can make a blanket statement that it's never correct to round a floating-point.  It depends on what you're doing with it.  If you're storing currency values, then yeah, it's wrong.  There are some MathContext rounding rules that I didn't get into that can address the half-up/half-down discrepancy.